# For which $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $p\geq1$ is $u(x):=|x|^\alpha$ in $L^p(B_1(0))$ and $H^{1,p}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\Omega:=B_1(0)\subset\mathbb{R}^d$, $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$, $p \geq 1$ and  $u:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, u(x):=|x|^\alpha$.

I want to find $\alpha$ and $p$ so that $u \in L^1(\Omega)$ and subsequently so that $u \in H^{1,p}$ (Sobolev Space). I've got a hint to find the weak derivative using polar coordinates.

I don't know where to start here; I think $\alpha$ should be greater or equal  than zero, but I am not entirely sure. And If I use polar coordinates for $\alpha\geq 0$ i only find that $$\int\limits_\Omega |u|^p=\frac{2}{1+p\alpha}\pi^{d-2}.$$

Comment: Your integral shows that $u \in L^p$ iff $1 + \alpha p > -1$. So this is the right way to answer the first part of the question. For the question about $H^{1,p}$, compute the gradient $D u$ and then $|D  u|$. This should also depend only on $r = |x|$ and in fact it will be of the same form as $u$ with a different $\alpha$, up to a constant. so you can use the same approach again.

Comment: @HansEngler That works for $d=2$ only. In general the condition is $\alpha p > -d.$

Comment: Do you mean for both $L^1$ and $H^{1,p}$? If so, could you elaborate how you deduce that from what I've got so far?

Comment: @Zolf69 - The function is in $L^1$ iff $\alpha > -d$. Your integral is incorrect - it should be $\frac{const.}{\alpha p + d}$, as the comment by zhw.  shows.